# Webkit browser fullscreen request changes body colour and removes console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently preparing a website which should switch the full website to fullscreen upon user request. I use the following function:

```
launchFullScreen(document.documentElement);

function launchFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}
```

Everything works fine in Edge, Chrome and FF, yet on Safari the body colour of my website gets turned from black to white - also the console of the browser becomes black so I cannot really see what's happening there. Any ideas?

Comment: Isnt that the browser setting for dark mode?

Comment: The console becomes plain black without distinguishable text - basically just a black bar. The website works as intended overall, just in fullscreen the body becomes white instead of black and the console becomes basically useless.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Safari somehow changed the background colour upon fullscreen request. Adding the following to the CSS of the page solved the issue:

```
    html:-webkit-full-screen {
        background-color: black !important;
    }
```